# Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ to show a property of a function

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Using the definition of continuity and the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit, how would you proceed to show that the following statement holds true?

*Let $f : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a continuos function at $x=0$, with the property that if $x\neq 0$ then $f(x)\geq 0$. Then $f(0) \geq 0$.*

My attempt so far has been to assume that $f(0) \lt 0$, which means that $$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\lt 0,$$
because of the continuity at the given point. Furthermore, I think this means that when $x$ approaches $0$ from both sides, at some point the value $f(x)\lt 0$, thus forming a contradiction.

I can't seem to see what to do afterwards. Is this a way of approaching the problem? And how will the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition come into play if my approach is usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of continuity we have,

$$|x-0| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(0)| < \epsilon \implies f(x) < f(0) + \epsilon$$  Now take $\epsilon = -f(0)/2$ to get a contradiction under the assumption that $f(0) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering. What is the argumentation behind assuming $\epsilon = -f(0)/2$? An why are we able to choose an $\epsilon$ like that?

Comment: @oslosl: By continuity we know that for any POSITIVE $\epsilon$ we have $f(x) < f(0) + \epsilon$ when $x$ is close to $0$.  Assuming $f(0) < 0$ we just need to pick SOME $\epsilon$ such that $f(0) + \epsilon < 0$ to get the contradiction of $f(x) < 0$.  The choice $\epsilon= -f(0)/2$ gets the job done since this $\epsilon$ is  positive and $f(0) + \epsilon = +f(0)/2 < 0$ .